# Save _POST values to an array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have an array of the names of my POST variables to use when I update a row in my database.

```
$jobs = array( "proposal_id",
               "will_provide",          
               "general_scope",          
               "per_bid",               
               "job_type");
```

Using this style my table is called jobs and each value in the array is a column id.

I want to edit this array so each item (column id) contains a single _POST Value

Then I have a function that uses the variables to create generic queries.

```
function save_data($jobs) {

        foreach ($jobs as $job)
        {

          $job[$job[$i]] = _$Post[$job];

              or

          Table_name[column] = cell value;

           ...
           ...
           ...
```

I would like to be able to save $values into the post variables associated to it. Something like

For example if I was going to manually create this array it would look like

```
    $jobs = array('proposal_id' => '12345678','title_of_project' => 'aTitle','creator' => 'aUser','last_modified' => '0000-00-00','date_created' => '0000-00-00','price' =>'1000');
```

Comment: `$jobs as $jobs` should be `$jobs as $job`

Comment: Like @Ghost said you should change the `$jobs` used in the for statement to be `$job` as well as fix the second instance of `$jobs` in the for loop to be `$job`. This may fix your problem, if it doesn't can you maybe explain what you want in another way or give an example of what you want.

Comment: In your last line of code, what's `$values`? The rest of your code doesn't use it. And in your loop, once you get the value from `$_POST` and put it in `$value`, what do you intend to do with `$value`? What you want isn't clear.

Comment: @BillTudor so is there only going to be one result? Because in your example you gave it you're using a for loop which would be used for multiple results. But in your example of how you want to use it with `$jobs['proposal_id']` this assumes there is only one result. Do you mean something like `$jobs[$i]['proposal_id']` is what you want?

Comment: @Fogest what you said is correct, I mean $jobs[$i]. I have about 50 values, and I was just trying to shorten my post. If I'm using the terminology correctly, I want to change the current values in my array to use as keys for my post variables.

Comment: So what does the $result variable have to do with this? Where are the 50 values coming from? The $jobs variable passed to the function?

Comment: Is the `$_POST[$jobs]` variable an array made via the html `name[]` style elements?

Comment: Nothing, it's used elsewhere in the function. I'll remove it from the post.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but what about my other comment?

Comment: No, $jobs is an array of columns in my database.

Comment: Okay and is there a `$_POST` variable for every job id then?

Comment: Yes every element in the $job array has a $_POST variable associated with it.

Comment: I gave a shot at the answer, I am not sure if I fully understand the question but I hope it works, if not let me know in a reply to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
$jobs = array( "proposal_id",
               "will_provide",          
               "general_scope",          
               "per_bid",               
               "job_type");

$jobValues = array();
foreach($jobs as $job) {
    $jobValues[] = isset($_POST[$job]) ? $_POST[$job] : null;
}

$jobs = array_combine($jobs, $jobValues);
```

Comment: Ok, would it be possible to use 'proposal_id' or any other variable in my $job array as my index instead of $i.

Comment: You can modify it as you like to use any unique variable as the `$jobResult` key.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm thinking. Basically I have my arrays set up as the name of the array is my db_table and each value in the db_table array is a column in my database. What I'm trying to do is keep this syntax while inserting the _post variable into each column.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm thinking. Basically I have my arrays set up as the name of the db_table and each value in the db_table array is a column in my database. What I'm trying to do is keep this syntax while inserting the _post variable into each column.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a very small example of what the array looks like before, and what you want the array to look like after? This would help me properly understand how you want it formatted. Right now I am slightly confused because I am trying to understand what the $jobs and $_POST arrays actually contain and how you actually want them formatted.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my post. This should give you the same result you gave as an example. I used array_combine as the starting array you have is an associative array already, but is using `0,1,2,3, etc` as the index, so using `array_combine` I could make those the keys instead, and use the `$jobValues` as the values for these keys. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: If there are any problems let me know, I'm headed to sleep but can address any issues in the morning. If this resolved your question I urge you to add an upvote if it helped and approve this answer. Thanks, have a good day :)